# How to get a pretty print for my input file

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a file that contains data as shown in the Input file below.  My program reads the config file, and writes section of this file as individual files.   I read this file using python3 and pyyaml module.   I get all the data  I want, but when the data is written out to the output file, instead of the pretty-printed output, there are all these extra characters  HOw can I get it pretty printed?
My ugly output:

```
"input {\n  beats {\n    port => 5044\n    host => \"0.0.0.0\"\n    tags => [\"output_beats\"\
  ]\n    add_field => {\n      \"[es][port]\" => 5044\n      \"[es][type]\" => \"\
  beats\" \n      \"[es][subtype]\" => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}\"\n      \"[@metadata][queue_prefix]\"\
  \ => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}\"\n    }\n  }\n}\n"
```

Input file:

```
---
# Source: logstash/templates/configmap-receiver.yaml
apiVersion: v1
... removed for clarity
data:
  100_beats_receiver_input_5044.conf : | 
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        tags => ["output_beats"]
        add_field => {
          "[es][port]" => 5044
          "[es][type]" => "beats" 
          "[es][subtype]" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
          "[@metadata][queue_prefix]" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
        }
      }
    }
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
def read_and_process_yaml_file(filePath, outputDir):
   """Read file, return parsed python structure"""
   print("About to read " + filePath)
   with open(filePath,'r') as input_file:
        yamlDocs = load_yaml(input_file)
        for doc in yamlDocs:
           print(yaml.dump(doc))
           if (doc is not None) \
              and (doc["kind"] is not None) and (doc["kind"].lower() == 'configmap') \
              and ("test" not in doc["metadata"]["name"]):
                 print("doc.name=" + doc["metadata"]["name"])
                 for name, data in doc["data"].items():
                    print("name=" + name)
                    basename = name.split(".",1)
                    filePath = outputDir + "/" + basename[0] + ".yaml"
                    print(name + "|-")
                    #print(yaml.dump(data))
                    write_yaml_file(yaml.dump(data), filePath)
```

Comment: I ran this command on the resulting files, and that did cleaned them up of the '\n':
for x in $(ls -1 *.yml); do echo $x;  sed -i -e 's/\\n/\'$'\n''/g' $x; done
but other extra characters are still there...

Answer (score 1):

`data` is the string containing the desired output. If you do `yaml.dump(data)`, you encode that string as a YAML scalar. Just do

```
write_yaml_file(data, filePath)
```